# Help for rewriting induced representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, modules, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup. My lecture book (Algebra by Cohn) defines the (right) $G$-module induced by a right $H$-module $U$ by
$$\tag{1}
\text{ind}_H^GU=U\otimes_H kG,
$$
where $kG$ is the group algebra. He writes that if we take a coset representation of $G$
$$\tag{2}
G=Ht_1\cup\dots \cup Ht_r,
$$
then we can write Equation $(1)$ as
$$\tag{3}
\text{ind}_H^GU=U\otimes Ht_1\oplus \dots\oplus U\otimes Ht_r.
$$
However, I am not sure how he gets from Equation $(1)$ to Equation $(3)$.
I think that one thing that makes it more confusing is that he uses sloppy notation. The group algebra is defined
$$\tag{4}
kG:=\Big\{\sum_{g\in G}a_g\boldsymbol{g}\mid a_g\in k\Big\}.
$$
Define
$$\tag{5}
(kH)t_i:=\Big\{\sum_{h\in H}a_h\boldsymbol{ht}_i\mid a_h\in k\Big\}.
$$
Since the collection of $t_i$ define a transversal, each $g\in G$ can be written uniquely in the form $ht_i$, so an arbitrary $\sum_{g\in G}a_g\boldsymbol{g}\in kG$ can be written uniquely in the form
$$\tag{6}
\sum_{g\in G}a_g\boldsymbol{g}=\sum_{h,i}a_{h}^{(t_i)}\boldsymbol{ht_i}=\sum_{i}\Big(\sum_{h}a_{h}^{(t_i)}\boldsymbol{ht_i}\Big).
$$
By definition of the direct sum of vector spaces, this implies that
$$\tag{7}
kG=\bigoplus_{i}(kH)t_i,
$$
Since the tensor product is distributive with respect to a direct sum, it then follows from Equation $(7)$ that we can rewrite Equation $(1)$ as
$$\tag{8}
\text{ind}_H^GU=U\otimes_H kG=\bigoplus_iU\otimes_H (kH)t_i.
$$
It therefore appears that when he writes $Ht_i$ in Equation $(3)$, he really means $(kH)t_i$. Is this correct, or am I misinterpreting something?

**Edit**: For vector spaces, we have the relation
$$
U\otimes (V\oplus W)\cong U\otimes V\oplus U\otimes W,
$$
so it appears that the induced $G$-module should really be written
$$
\text{ind}_H^G\cong \bigoplus_iU\otimes_H (kH)t_i.
$$
So when Cohn writes an equality does he really mean an isomorphism?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: And to answer your edit: often equalities are used in place of isomorphisms (abuse of language), but this can be an actual equality if you interpret direct sums as *internal* direct sums.